# Who to "enable Magento to use the distributed configuration file .htaccess"?

Tags: magento2, installation, .htaccess, apache2

One of the steps in this [Magento Apache2 installation guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache.html) is to "*enable Magento to use the distributed configuration file .htaccess*". In that step, they have a link to [Apache2 page guideline](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) .... 
That Apache2 page is so confusing and I'm lost what to do exactly to enable Magento2 to use the distributed configuration file .htaccess...

**Can anyone list the steps to achieve so in simple words?** .... please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree about apache's website, it's not the clearest.

Just make sure that the .htaccess file that comes with Magento 2 is in the root directory of your site.

on your apache server run

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

then in your `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride  All
</Directory>
```

then

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Alternatively you can use a vhosts conf file instead of the 000-default one, and use that particular directory instead of /var/www/html

Comment: thanks ... but where in 000-default.conf should I place:
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride  All
</Directory>

  ..........also I would like to note that I'm using apache 2.4, does that make any difference in your answer?

thanks again :)

Comment: you can put it at the bottom below `</VirtualHost>`. The answer is for 2.4.

Comment: Thanks again ... but what if my Magento2 files are not under "/var/www/html" do I still need to keep that attribute as it is or change it to "/var/www/Magento2" which is the folder containing my Magento2 files? .... and also what do you mean by "vhosts conf file"? and where is "that" when you said "and use that particular directory" ? excuse me but again I'm shallow in this

Comment: Yes exactly, so change the directory to the one you're use for your magento files. Vhosts is just a way to use multiple sites on one server. usually they go under `/var/www/vhosts/yoursite.com` or something. This is a good intro to all that - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts